# How to detect implicit conversion losses integer precision on std::vector::emplace_back

Tags: c++, vector, warnings, implicit-conversion, emplace

I compiled the following code with `-Wconversion` compiler option to detect implicit conversion loses integer precision:

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::uint16_t> v;
    std::uint32_t a = 0;
    v.emplace_back(a);  // no warning
    v.push_back(a);     // warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision
}
```

Compiling Demo https://wandbox.org/permlink/K5E4sUlfGBw6C5w8

The vector's `value_type` is `std::uint16_t`. 
If I `push_back` `std::uint32_t` value to the vector, then I got the following warning as I expected.

```
prog.cc:8:17: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'std::uint32_t' (aka 'unsigned int') to 'std::__1::vector<unsigned short, std::__1::allocator<unsigned short> >::value_type' (aka 'unsigned short') [-Wimplicit-int-conversion]
v.push_back(a);     // warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision
  ~~~~~~~~~ ^
1 warning generated.
```

However, if I `emplace_back` the same value to the vector, no warning is detected.

I've tested it clang++ 10.0.0, clang++ 9.0.0, and g++ 9.3.0 and got the same result.

Is there any good way to detect implicit conversion losses integer precision on std::vector::emplace_back ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Forbid integer conversion with precision loss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45283273/forbid-integer-conversion-with-precision-loss)

Comment: @KyleKnoepfel Good find. I'll go along with the duplicate flag being a better result than my answer.

Comment: I understand that my question is the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45283273/forbid-integer-conversion-with-precision-loss. There is no marked answer the question but I understand why warning is not reported by https://stackoverflow.com/a/45300370/1922763 answer. However it is difficult to find expected warning in many spurious warnings. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62462385/1922763 gives me better solution that providing explicit template argument to emplace_back. The situation is my question is duplicated but got better answer that solves my question. How should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no implicit conversion when you call `v.emplace_back(a)`. There would be an implicit conversion if you called `v.emplace_back<const std::uint16_t &>(a)`.

A key difference between `push_back` and `emplace_back` is that the latter is a template while the former is not. If you do not specify a template argument for `emplace_back`, the compiler deduces it from the function argument, which means no conversion will be necessary at the point of call. Within `emplace_back` the conversion happens in a system header, which suppresses the warning.

So in your example,

```
v.emplace_back(a);
```

is deduced as

```
v.emplace_back<const std::uint32_t &>(a);
```

where the function argument is expected to be a `std::uint32_t`. Perfect match, no conversion necessary outside the system header. If you were to enable warnings within system headers, you could end up with a bunch of spurious warnings

To get an implicit conversion in your code, you need to force `emplace_back` to expect a `std::uint16_t`, which can be done via

```
v.emplace_back<const std::uint16_t &>(a);
```

This would implicitly convert `a` to `std::uint16_t` before calling `emplace_back`, triggering the compiler warning in the same way that `push_back` does.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I didn't come up with explicit template argument approach. I reported the problem to GCC bugzilla https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=95765 . The report marked as duplicated but Jonathan Wakely  fixed the warnings in the libstdc++. Before the fix https://godbolt.org/z/jmkc5W after the fix https://godbolt.org/z/9TmShD. Noisy warnings are disappeared. Maybe this is just one part of standard library warning problems but it has actually been improved.